# Docker compose service does not expose ports

Tags: docker, elixir, docker-compose, phoenix-framework, docker-network

So I'm building an Elixir/Phoenix application and I've got the following `docker-compose` service:

```
dev:
    extends:
      service: common
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: "postgres.dev"
      MIX_ENV: dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: >
      bash -c '
      cd $$APP_HOME \
      && mix ecto.create \
      && mix ecto.migrate \
      && iex -S mix phx.server'
```

and this effectively runs the app on `0.0.0.0:4000`:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

[info] Running MyApp.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000
```

Checking with `docker ps` the ports are not exposed:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7a1d80cf0511        app_dev         "bash -c ' cd $APP..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                 app_dev_run_2
ef7bed51cf24        postgres:10.0       "docker-entrypoint..."   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   app_postgres_1
```

While the Postgres service has the exposed port and I effectively can connect to it via a GUI:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:10.0
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - postgres.dev
    restart: always
```

I don't understand why the `dev` service does not expose the ports when they're the exact same command/definitions but using 4000 instead of 5432.

I've tried stopping, deleting all containers, networks and images but this still persists.

I don't have any `EXPOSE` commands in my Dockerfile and I'm running the service with `docker-compose run dev`.

Any help?

Comment: You just said it, you are not exposing any PORTS so therefore, your container doesn't talk to the outside world. Try exposing a port in your dockerfile and then use it in your docker-compose file and see what happens

Comment: I thought EXPOSE is just meant to open ports between containers?

As per the docs:

The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to to high-order ports.

Comment: EXPOSING a port means opening that port on your host, so for example I have an NGINX container which listens on port 443, therefore in my docker file I will have something like EXPOSE 443 and then when I run my container, i will run it as docker run -p 1234:443 sergiu/nginx, which allow me to connect to 1234 OUTSIDE and 443 INSIDE the container

Comment: Like in your example postgres is exposing 5432 :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. EXPOSE 4000 resulted in 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5806f4c39387        app_dev         "bash -c ' cd $APP..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   4000/tcp                 app_dev_run_1

But the port still isn't exposed to the host. To actually expose it (i.e., obtain `0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp`  in `docker ps`) I can do it running `docker run -p 4000:4000 app_dev` but I'd like to obtain the same behaviour with a `docker-compose` service

Comment: It seems this is what `ports` should be doing in `docker-compose`:

ports
Expose ports.

SHORT SYNTAX

Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (a random host port will be chosen).

Comment: hold on you are extending from the postgres image?

Comment: I don't this I am. Here is my common service:

version: '2'

services:
  common:
    build:
      context: .
    networks:
      - default

Comment: I've been looking at several examples and my docker-compose file seems completely fine to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally solved this, I just had to pass the `--service-ports` in `docker run`:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/